# How to update sysroot directory for Xcode (after Xcode 12.3 update)

Tags: xcode, leveldb

I just updated Xcode to 12.3, but now when I try to build my project it's giving me this error:

[image]

I checked the directory listed for the sysroot warning and I saw that now there's a file called iPhoneOS14.3.sdk, but what do I need to change in my project to make it compatible with that instead of iPhoneOS14.2.sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my computer and everything worked fine.